# InvalidCast exception thrown when TypeCasting Int64 value to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I am Typecasting an `Int64` value to `JValue` and I am able to Typecast it. But when I store that Int64 Value in a variable of type `object` and then try to Typecast it, why it throws an  InvalidCast Exception?.

```
     Int64 Int64Value = Int64.MaxValue;

        // Int64 value can be TypeCasted to JValue
        Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue output = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue) Int64Value;
        
        // Storing Int64 value in variable of type object
        object Int64ValueInObject = Int64Value;

        try
        {
            // Why this code throws exception ?
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue output1 = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(Int64ValueInObject);
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException ex )
        {
            // {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue'."}
           // However, from above code it is seen that Int64 can be casted to JValue
        }
```

Comment: For the same reason that you can't do `long x = (long)(object)3`. When you unbox a value, the cast you use has to exactly match the type of the boxed value

Comment: The confusion comes from the fact that the cast syntax `(T)x` is used to mean many different things in C#. It's used for built-in and user-defined conversions (e.g. `(long)3`), but also for boxing/unboxing (e.g. `(object)3` and `(int)(object)3`), among other things. However, the rules for the different sorts of operations are different

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to unbox an object of type `object` which is boxing an `Int64` directly to type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue`. You have to unbox to the exact type before doing any conversions. In this case, that means something like the following:

```
  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue output1 = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)(Int64)(Int64ValueInObject);
```